# Why three.js textured faces are looking askew when rotated?

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping, uv-mapping

What's wrong in the example below?

The faces are looking askew when they are not parallel to the viewport.

http://jsfiddle.net/mneja2mr/

```
    geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10, 10, 10);

    texture=new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(dataUrl);                                          

    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture
    });

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
```

Comment: do you definitely want to use the CanvasRenderer? you can use the WebGLRenderer.

Comment: The example works with WebGLRenderer I feel stupid :-) , but I have the same problem in a page with WebGLRenderer where I set the vertices positions of a plane - I suppose I failed to make the vertices coplanar because of some rotation...  I forked an existing jsfiddle to check it out, without noticing the renderer type.. :-)

Comment: also note that your texture is not power of 2 and maybe the Canvas renderer has an issue with that. If that is true you can open an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The CanvasRenderer do not interpolate attributes correctly for perspective cameras; this break texture mapping.
If you need to render with CanvasRenderer, a quick fix is to subdivide the geometry: http://jsfiddle.net/41g0ffb3/2/

```
geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10);
```